# How to analyze S-R latch circuits?

Tags: digital-logic, latch

I'm trying to understand the circuit below (from the [Apollo Guidance Computer](https://archive.org/stream/BlockISchematics#page/n163/mode/1up)), which is two S-R latches connected together. The top input resets the output and the bottom input sets the output. But there's more going on than a plain S-R latch, maybe the bottom input is edge-triggered?

[image: Schematic of four NOR gates connected to form a latch.]

I'm trying to analyze this circuit by drawing out the states, but I keep getting messed up. Is there a strategy for understanding this sort of circuit?

Comment: Maybe it’s designed so that one input is dominant (I’m guessing the upper one.)

Comment: I modeled this in Falstad using discrete NPNs. With both inputs low, the power-on state shows up as mid-level. Added this to my answer.

Comment: would it be possible to get a scope trace of this circuit power on behavior? I’m guessing that the inputs don’t enter the problematic start-up condition. Ultimately, the answer to ‘how’ is that this is an async state machine, so you’d create a state diagram for it showing the legal and illegal states.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tl; dr version: Simulate it. Sim reveals unpredictable power-on behavior, which is probably why you don't see latches made this way anymore.

I see by inspection that both inputs high forces a known state. I started with this and analyzed what happens when when you change one input at a time.

The latch init sim problem is apparently known, more here: https://www.ibiblio.org/apollo/Verilog.html#Step_4:_The_Test_BenchTBD

Another observation: This schematic is from Block 1. Block 2 has one that I found, on page 2005070, "Module No. A19 INOUT IV". [Link](https://archive.org/stream/apertureCardBox460NARASW_images/apertureCardBox460NARASW#page/n67/mode/1up)

---

**Simulation**

I threw together a Falstad Spice sim for this. This has both the RTL gate version as NPN discretes and also constructed from gates so you can compare them side-by-side.

Try it here ([Falstad Sim](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWK0AsAmAnADgOxaxpAGwDMkGCaRKIlttktApgLRhgBQA5iCmESDY4BfAWyKNJHAE4gSaRizT45aQcqxQQaBRwDuvfurQ1RgsMKj7VinTXmKLAyDLlFNSlIxLvzlxjpwrmg4ap4BoX7O2gouBmZKKgloCM7WDupJRomacTaZmhlKqVYALm4eJozJXloQLDBYCHDuEriUOBhEEDCQOGBVWH0I%20Ozs4HAgACZMAGYAhgCuADalHOUhYVX54XWCMFRgJAgDGJjYVFg0MEQIGBRYAyQk6KQqYJMzCytrALK8XUEJzUCBQNBYwLq0Cw3EMYi81WyJCuWhcsiKkPkQIGWkC1gSYM0BMmeSKhJ2CKsABlVNiwtQ6XsFssAM5MOTQNLo3wsFAMnweSkBWLBSK8hmbQRCmJBeLZSEEoZWAwYnEJSGkhSMslKlzlAVShkEhmMeoHW4SPpEFKQBBkUHIW5dch8LDPagYPkTRhfJardbaMV8%20xa8XXcD7aBnSgfCxNLCkEiWNDQFKg60kM7UK6PFCsDDe6ZzP1reIoSpZMQaZUAsQKwFsZQ19Vq8uMvIoBsKtsQnEdnvdjzHNR5bYsDJjpw1yfJsVT-sVok9jKknmUg3juh5JW8yaS3dSGk7yniKUkrTMtkctJgO0gAh1psfSAeSi5bRaBAcW8ke8NszPoKRgBJ%201gPoy%20CKBqYE7pCkFSrqMGKOWpqQCYhrXNYHzoWGEw4WYeTYeCAFwEBaQGOBvJYvBVEjlhpFAk%20aHgm%20NZEYxmjsbygKEcxUqAjRwY1oJDKCVi247nY947mAZxsXxxQCDRUm8Th1ZcSk5HeoueHgtW24NrJag0UZ8k4VOgFRGZenoVx85IeotQaehEm2JEym1AZVbuZJkQuD%20f5iBZDFCNEI60N%20d6UepIX6R%20jBfgYHxiqxHy1BCTaqSxTHpaxvG5TligGvlRW%20DR7rCTuFXlZAmEUVVtWBYIZB1bpBRteOWpZc1Wrlb4rnNWVx4kg5B5NWNLhHl2YL3gOM2SCAl7skgk3jfwjA5uYEioot8ysstVj-MlYSpWlHG4tAX48EUU43dtUgqjyw68MuXX4sudBjiusJkpMRTIuGLgAB7mD4QIvOAJ0kBANDoQACgA9noTDSAAOiyADKiwAA7Y8sACe6RbCoWK9nR11avyvULQu4A4tsYDzekvjsGo5KM5hFMBCTWotaiHBHt4dCns9C1Lde061BKkQmszmj8izfbvZxljs0zFFC2oBqi8rCEvZxSvxP%20S6Crk%20LZG25K8mbZYqyIRj2Rsfn5AtPSXXw8jQ8oOgDAgODXJyvukBgzw4HajOPIWvo-AGxVwjtbt3EQYfuiEIcoHgK2csn9yiG6KQ%20HJz5Ft8-oqqGbZ3TWOrx9bzYW0S2TAaK4WSiaMpohUWgGu3gSaqaAgZLLcoCEYZiy%20iFeFGEbbCi4PDj6YRi6odtZ66CxHvmA0IBpKUkTi5Ebjqm1poEcskh0MYcjrA-SDAMBDlt7SDF9H-r6r4UlmCpR8kNAzwvFBHADOZ9sBGBwJdO0dxIIUE6EQCg%20Yo7FhjuXU0lgJwvmrlqKcAF-Dm1HqrIwCgzayD3uhPeKg56dwNPvT%20lCO5EwCLUCclD8HaFqN-Vhk80GDzUPOGUsJOGN0Ho1B6tIcjiNnkTPWWJ7IGAZjNbY%20lrBKJUBQm2Xdqzay3PiQyTYxyIXkelJU2xh5rzrp2MQPE5ZWQ3BzauPJ7GWMENYg0ziya0G2ryWeVg3HG08QPfmCM6YRkRGhcAqYs49HABwYJdxQm8HIAWLO8ByDCFSCkCMIICwkA4EAA))

- RTL, power on with inputs L,L: sticks at ~900mV. Cycling the lower input clears the condition
- Gates, power on with inputs L,L: oscillates. Only both inputs high clears it

Finally, the functionality seems to be, for upper, lower input:

- Lower input H: pass through upper input (inverted)
- Lower input L: allow one high-low pulse on output

  - if upper input was high, allow L-H-L out (toggle twice)
  - if upper input was low, allow H-L out (toggle once)

Comment: It's either RTL or DTL, so it has a pullup at input anyways.

Comment: Doesn't matter - RTL and DTL gates still have amplification in them and could still oscillate under the right circumstances. At this point it probably needs a SPICE sim to model power-up behavior. I don't consider it a safe circuit.

Comment: LabView software will not oscillate under normal conditions. Once initialized the code can only be in 1 of 2 states. Toggling gates other than RESET or SET is not a rational thing to do. In hardware RESET likely has a pullup, and oscillating is not possible due to its tendency to latch in 1 of 2 states. I am satisfied with my analysis of this circuit.

Comment: If you are getting oscillations it could be due to race conditions. I set my Tpd to 1ms.

Comment: I used a unit delay of 1ns just to model some delay. In Icarus (tutorialspoint...) it oscillates. In Vivado it doesn't. Turns out it's an issue generally, added a link to my answer.

Answer (score 7):

This is a S-R latch for the most part, but an extra latch is added up top with two feedback paths. This is to make sure that RESET always overrides SET if both commands occur at the same time.

Also a SET will not work unless the latch has been 
RESET (initialized). This extra logic is to block irrational duplicate commands from entering the computer.

**NOTE**: Only one RESET or one SET command can be entered at a time (**state is maintained**). If both commands are entered RESET will dominate. The double feedback posed a behaviour question, so I built this in LabView to see its true behaviour. This is what I observed:

[image]

Note that power-up without a RESET results in a unknown output state. Also only 5 (including un-initialized) rational states are possible with the schematic provided. Other possible states involving various open gate inputs should be posted as a separate question.

**EDIT:** To really understand multi-stage logic it is best to buy a breadboard plus the ICs and a 5 volt supply and build the circuits yourself. A single 74LS02 or 74HC02 can be wired at least 7 different ways.

**Our software versions work fine for fixed patterns like the image you show, but showing a wide range of "what-if" scenarios would take many pages to answer.**

Comment: That’s the issue with the circuit - the latches can power up in either state. It needs to be analyzed for all those conditions. It may very well be that reset dominates, but you haven’t proven that and neither have I.

Comment: See below my revised answer. Half the power-up states are unstable and will oscillate. I encourage you to try it yourself.